# GPU doesn't work when I request PoseNet API (@tensorflow-models/posenet) with node.js and express

Tags: node.js, express, tensorflow.js

#### Problem

Excuse me.
I implemented demo app with tensorflow-models/posenet(https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/posenet), node.js(https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-node) and express(https://github.com/expressjs/express).
I replaced the sample code as follows, but GPU may not work when executing estimateMultiplePoses()(https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/blob/master/posenet/src/posenet_model.ts).
Could you tell me how to run my code on GPU?

For example, I got a very low response when I post my API to a localhost server.

```
$curl -X POST -F thumbnail=@./picture.png localhost:3000/upload
```

[At server log]
I want to get the response less than 100 ms.
I got the response less than 30 ms when I didn't use PoseNet API, so thought that this low response was caused by not running on GPU.

```
POST /upload 200 2110.888 ms - 9372
```

However,  the process may be alive when building the server.

```
$ nvidia-smi
Tue Jul 31 10:27:38 2018       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 396.37                 Driver Version: 396.37                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 107...  On   | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 27%   40C    P8    13W / 180W |   7732MiB /  8116MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 107...  On   | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 27%   38C    P8    12W / 180W |   7723MiB /  8119MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1252      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           281MiB |
|    0      2068      G   compiz                                       226MiB |
|    0      2435      G   ...-token=...                                 61MiB |
|    0      2697      G   unity-control-center                          15MiB |
|    0      2945      G   ...-token=...                                 92MiB |
|    0     14062      G   ...-token=...                                 66MiB |
|    0     26892      C   node                                        6983MiB |
|    1     26892      C   node                                        7711MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

regards.

---

#### Custom Code

./routes/index.js

```
var posenet = require('@tensorflow-models/posenet');
var tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu');

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({dest: "./uploads/"}).single('thumbnail');
var Canvas = require('canvas');
var Image = Canvas.Image;

const state = {
  input: {
    imageScaleFactor: 0.5,
    flipHorizontal: false,
    outputStride: 16,
  },
  detection: {
    maxPoseDetections: 5,
    minPoseConfidence: 0.15,
    minPartConfidence: 0.1,
    nmsRadius: 30.0,
  },
};

function createHTMLCanvasElementFromRequest(req){
    const img = new Image;
    img.src = req.file.path;
    const canvas = new Canvas(img.width,img.height); 
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
    return canvas;
}

function detectPoses(req, res){
  const canvas = createHTMLCanvasElementFromRequest(req);
  async function usePoseNet(req){
    const net = await posenet.load();
    const poses = await net.estimateMultiplePoses(  canvas, 
                                                  state.input.imageScaleFactor, 
                                                  state.input.flipHorizontal, 
                                                  state.input.outputStride, 
                                                  state.detection.maxPoseDetections,
                                                  state.detection.minPartConfidence, 
                                                  state.detection.nmsRadius);
    return poses;
  }
  usePoseNet(req).then( json_res =>{
    res.send({
        "OriginalName": req.file.originalname,
        "FileName": req.file.filename,
        "Size": req.file.size,
        "Width": canvas.width,
        "Height": canvas.height,
        "Context": json_res
    })
  }).catch(e => {
    res.send({
        "Error": e
    });
  });
}

function failedToGetImages(req,res, err){
  res.send({
        "Destination": req.file.destination,
        "Error": err
      });
}

router.post('/upload', function(req, res){
  upload(req, res, function(err){
    res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    err? failedToGetImages(req,res,err) : detectPoses(req, res);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

---

./app.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Max-Age', '86400');
  next();
});

app.options('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendStatus(200);
});


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});


module.exports = app;
```

---

./bin/www

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('roboserver:server');
var http = require('http');

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

---

#### System information

- OS Platform and Distribution:  ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
- TensorFlow installed from: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs
- TensorFlow version: 0.12.0
- CUDA/ cuDNN: 8.0/6.0
- GPU model: GeForce GTX 1070 Ti 8GB * 2
- Memory:

  SMBIOS 3.0.0 present.
  Handle 0x0043, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
  Physical Memory Array
      Location: System Board Or Motherboard
      Use: System Memory
      Error Correction Type: None
      Maximum Capacity: 32 GB
      Error Information Handle: Not Provided
      Number Of Devices: 2

  Handle 0x0044, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
  Memory Device
      Array Handle: 0x0043
      Error Information Handle: Not Provided
      Total Width: Unknown
      Data Width: Unknown
      Size: No Module Installed
      Form Factor: Unknown
      Set: None
      Locator: ChannelA-DIMM1
      Bank Locator: BANK 0
      Type: Unknown
      Type Detail: None
      Speed: Unknown
      Manufacturer: Not Specified
      Serial Number: Not Specified
      Asset Tag: Not Specified
      Part Number: Not Specified
      Rank: Unknown
      Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
      Minimum Voltage: Unknown
      Maximum Voltage: Unknown
      Configured Voltage: Unknown

  Handle 0x0045, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
  Memory Device
      Array Handle: 0x0043
      Error Information Handle: Not Provided
      Total Width: 64 bits
      Data Width: 64 bits
      Size: 16384 MB
      Form Factor: DIMM
      Set: None
      Locator: ChannelA-DIMM2
      Bank Locator: BANK 1
      Type: DDR4
      Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
      Speed: 2133 MHz
      Manufacturer: Corsair
      Serial Number: 00000000
      Asset Tag: 9876543210
      Part Number: CMK32GX4M2B3000C15
      Rank: 2
      Configured Clock Speed: 2133 MHz
      Minimum Voltage: Unknown
      Maximum Voltage: Unknown
      Configured Voltage: 1.2 V

  Handle 0x0046, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
  Memory Device
      Array Handle: 0x0043
      Error Information Handle: Not Provided
      Total Width: Unknown
      Data Width: Unknown
      Size: No Module Installed
      Form Factor: Unknown
      Set: None
      Locator: ChannelB-DIMM1
      Bank Locator: BANK 2
      Type: Unknown
      Type Detail: None
      Speed: Unknown
      Manufacturer: Not Specified
      Serial Number: Not Specified
      Asset Tag: Not Specified
      Part Number: Not Specified
      Rank: Unknown
      Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
      Minimum Voltage: Unknown
      Maximum Voltage: Unknown
      Configured Voltage: Unknown

  Handle 0x0047, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
  Memory Device
      Array Handle: 0x0043
      Error Information Handle: Not Provided
      Total Width: 64 bits
      Data Width: 64 bits
      Size: 16384 MB
      Form Factor: DIMM
      Set: None
      Locator: ChannelB-DIMM2
      Bank Locator: BANK 3
      Type: DDR4
      Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
      Speed: 2133 MHz
      Manufacturer: Corsair
      Serial Number: 00000000
      Asset Tag: 9876543210
      Part Number: CMK32GX4M2B3000C15
      Rank: 2
      Configured Clock Speed: 2133 MHz
      Minimum Voltage: Unknown
      Maximum Voltage: Unknown
      Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
- Exact command to reproduce: node ./bin/www
- Browser: Google Chrome
- npm: 6.1.0
- node: 10.6.0
- @tensorflow-models/posenet: 0.2.2
- @tensorflow/tfjs-node: 0.1.9
- @tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu: 0.1.9
- gcc: 5.4.0

Comment: Did you ever have luck with this? I too have had similar issues with tfjs-node-gpu and GPU utilization. A tfjs-node-gpu contributor described a similar performance problem to me in [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/468). I'd be curious if your problem is related.

Comment: Thanks to your comment. I haven't have this solution yet. I gave up developing ML projects with tfjs-node-gpu.

Comment: It should automatically detect GPU?